# Convergence of coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

Let $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathrm{N}}$ $\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$  and $\left(b_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathrm{N}}$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ ; $
f_{n}(x)=a_{n} \cos \left(n x+b_{n}\right) \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$.

Let $E$  be a Borelian of $\mathbb{R}$ of finite and non-zero Lebesgue measure such that
$$
\forall x \in E, \quad \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n}(x)=0
$$
How can I show that $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathrm{N}}$ converges to $0 \,?$

Looking at this problem, I remembered the proofs of the statements that the coefficients of the Fourier series and the Fourier integral tend to zero (they were proven using the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma). But here we don't have neither series nor integrals.